# images are not showing in frontend

Tags: image, frontend

recently I've made www.einzigwebshop.nl using Magento and untill a few weeks ago it worked like a charm. However, now I can't seem to get my images working on front-end. They work just fine back-end!

I have CHMOD my media folder to 777
reindexing cache and store does not work
store view is correct
image, thumbnail and image_small are all set and NOT excluded
.HTaccess in /media/ is renamed
safe mode of PHP is OFF

It still does not work!

After searching for a solution for hours it doesn't seem to make my life any easier as all posted solutions are not working.

Help me out please, I'm desperate!

Comment: You mean on the product view page? Because in the list everything shows up.

Comment: Yes, the list shows everything perfectly, try clicking on any product and you'll get a blank space where the image is supposed to be and then the description.

Answer (score 1):

The section where the image should be renders an empty div:

```
<div class="product-img-box" style="width:277px;">
</div>
```

Make sure you don't have an extension that changed your `media.phtml` file, or if nothing is commented in that file.
Also check the var/log folder for errors.

Turn on template path hints to see what template should be rendered in that section.
I don't think the problem is related to server misconfiguration. It's code issue.

Comment: Appreciate that, it's been my first and only Magento shop made as of yet. I have no clue as to how to change that! Where can I find the media.phtml file and why's there a P before the 'html' part? Typo?

Comment: @DennisKlaster. NO typo. that's what it is `phtml`. Like I said. Turn on the template path hints. This is how: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-template-path-hints-magento. And your should see the exact file that is rendered in the section where the image should be. Then look for that file and see if something is wrong in it.

Comment: I have done that, and found absolutely nothing. Also been checking the safe and unsafe paths in the Magento settings and still nothing..

Comment: Anyone else have any sort of clue of what's wrong? I am too much of a noob in Magento to be able to fix this myself and I've been bogging my head on it for the past 2 days!